# accessibilityIdentifier nil when set in xib, must be set from User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When I set `accessibilityIdentifier` in Interface Builder's *Accessibility -> Enabled -> Identifier* section, the `.accessibilityIdentifier` property of the associated view is `nil` at runtime.

**However, when I set it via `User Defined Runtime Attributes` it works fine.**

"User Defined Runtime Attributes" is a workaround, but a confusing and 'ancient secrets' one that I would feel silly explaining to an Android developer. "Oh, that field doesn't work, you have to set it up there, in the place that says nothing about the thing we're actually setting"

**Has anyone else seen this? Is this new with Xcode 7?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same problem in Xcode 7 when using the default Accessibility area but only on iOS 8. 
On iOS 9 the `accessibilityIdentifier` is NOT `nil`.